# How can I troubleshoot using ssh remotely Through a Static IP?

Tags: macos, command-line, mojave, ssh

Like so many others at the moment, we're forced to work remotely. I’m not able to ssh in and would like assistance in configuration or troubleshooting steps.

Using a screen sharing app I've been able to access our server behind a static IP and push files to our 2TB Dropbox account so the whole office has files they need to keep working.

Unfortunately the connection periodically breaks, and no amount of attempts can get the GUI to reconnect. Fortunately the facilities manager at our building has been willing to reboot the machine, and we're back. I don't want to continue to ask that favor.

I'm hoping that someone can provide the command line prompt that will pass me through the static IP, so I can SSH user@machine_address -r.

It's been a while since I've needed to run commands, so the rust is hard.

Following up, I've opened port 22 on the Comcast-supplied Cisco router for SSH connections, but when I hit the IP address I get a "connection refused". If I watch the logs I can see the traffic come through. It appears this may not be an issue with the router, but rather, with Mojave.

How can I assess or narrow down what is failing?

Comment: There's no command that will "pass you through a static IP" as you describe.   If the server's not responding, it's not responding.  It's like asking for a special key that will start a car when it won't start  What you need to look for is the cause of the server hanging up. What Model Mac is it?  What version of macOS?

Comment: Also: what does „connection breaks“ mean? Does the screen sharing crash but the machine keeps running? Do you know the static IP (I assume you do as you need it for screen sharing as well) and just to enable SSH on the Mac and on whatever firewall your company has in place?

Comment: In response to @nohillside, yes, I have a static IP. Using a screen-sharing app (had been using iTeleport, now using Screens4) there have been two instances where, when I try to reconnect, the connection fails, and the machine keeps running. I know the machine is running because I've asked the facilities manager at the building to do a reboot. On reboot the connection can be established. I'd like to be able to issue a reboot command by SSH in order to avoid asking the FM to again reboot the machine.

Comment: So did you enable remote login on the Mac as well?

Comment: You have to enable remote login on the Mac before you can connect via SSH (and make sure you’re forwarding port 22 properly!) That said, it won’t fix the issue with your machine locking up,  you may have to go on site to diagnose.  Also,  it sounds like your not using a proper firewall between the router and your network I would look at pfSense (there’s) a free version.   Let me know if you need help with any of this.

Comment: I'd look in the console app to see why you are crashing.

Comment: Yes, VNC is open on port 5900 and SSH on port 22 on the router. Remote login and SSH are enabled on the Mac Mini running Mojave Server. Note that the machine isn't crashing. The issue is that the VNC connection will drop, so using a screen sharing app can no longer establish a connection. If the machine is rebooted a connection can be reestablished, but that's only possible standing at the machine. Watching the sshd log, I can see the request coming in on the Mini. For some reason the SSH connection is refused.

Comment: A a general rule, things *time out* if they aren't running and are *refused* when they are blocked.  Refused means something is seeing the connection and responding back with "get out, you can't connect."  Look for a firewall either on the Mac or at the router.  Just because a port is *open* doesn't mean it's going where it needs to.